# Vuetify Tabs change active when scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I've vuetify tabs implemented with [vue-scrollto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto) that when you click a tab it will scroll to a position.

```
       <v-tabs
          centered
          grow
          color="#009EE2"
        >
          <div class="slider-background" />
          <v-tabs-slider />

          <v-tooltip
            bottom
            v-for="(tab, key) in tabs"
            :key="key"
            color="#009EE2"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
              <v-tab
                v-on="on"
                v-scroll-to="{
                  el: tab.scrollTo,
                  container: scrollContainer,
                  duration: 300,
                  easing: 'linear',
                  offset: -120,
                  force: true,
                  cancelable:true
                }"
              >
                <v-icon v-text="tab.icon" />
              </v-tab>
            </template>
            <div class="v-tooltip-arrow" />
            <span>
              {{ $t(tab.tooltipText) }}
            </span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-tabs>
```

So what I want to achieve now is that when scrolling the active tab changes depending on the position.

I've searched for days and I haven't found anything. [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs)

Is there a way without using JQuery?

Result example with JQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Comment: You can use the IntersectionObserver API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) or the `onScroll` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By combining the `href` attribute for tabs, and an [intersection observer](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect#intersection-observer), you can accomplish this.

Here's a rudimentary, but working, pen: https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/VwYEapg

Effectively, what we're doing here is assigning an anchor to each tag, and tying that to a data property. Then, we have a span at the bottom of the page with an intersection observer, using Vuetify's `v-intersect` wrapper:

```html
<span v-intersect ="handleIntersect">Page will automatically scroll to tab-3 when this span is in view</span>
```

This intersect wrapper calls a user-defined method (in this case, `handleIntersect`) to update the tab:

```js
        handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
            if(entries[0].isIntersecting) {
                this.tab = "tab-3"
            }
            else {
                this.tab = "tab-1"
            }
        }
```

For your use case, maybe each item that *would* change a tab based on its viewport position would need to call a given function with an argument for which tab to set. That's not much of a stretch from where this Pen is currently.

**Note:** I've never used IntersectionObserver and I'm not certain if `isIntersecting` is the best way to detect an element's existence in the viewport, so do your own research and testing before implementing this in production code :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I have achieved it successfully without using any external library like vue-scrollto.

Tabs -

```
<v-tabs vertical v-model="tab_selected" >
      <span v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
        <v-tab @click="$vuetify.goTo('#sec_'+index)" class="nav_tab">
          {{category.name}}
        </v-tab>
      </span>

    </v-tabs>
```

Here I have bound the tab selection to a v-model and the scroll to the required div happens with $vuetify.goTo() (more here - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/scrolling/)

The Scrollable content is held in a free flowing div -

```
<div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
        <v-card :id="'sec_'+index" class="card-shadow mb-10">
          <span :id="'span_'+index" v-intersect="handleIntersect"></span>
          ...
        </v-card>
      </div>
```

In the above scanario, the tabs and the scrollable content are held in a col-4 and a col-8 respectively.

There are 2 parts to this. On clicking of the tab, the div should scroll to the correct content. This is handled by $vuetify.goTo(). the second is on scrolling the content div, the relevant tab should be selected. This is handled by the v-intersect directive. (more here - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect/)

```
<span :id="'span_'+index" v-intersect="handleIntersect"></span>
```

The handleIntent function will fire when the said span is in and out of view. In the handleIntent function, I detect the index of the span which is in view and then activate the tab via v-model.

```
handleIntersect(entries, observer){
  let intersecting_element = entries[0]
  if(intersecting_element.isIntersecting){
    let id = intersecting_element.target.id
    let index = Number(id.split("_")[1])
    this.tab_selected = index
  }
}
```

This is how it looks - https://gyazo.com/388550a03d66e086d7dc00b646264806

Cheers!